# Play Java Akka - Await.result expecting awaitable object and not accepting Future<Object>

Tags: java, akka

I am new to play framework and AKKA and I am a Java developer. I use Play 2.3.7 and IntelliJ 14. I called Pattern.ask and this returns a Future object which has a String from web service call. Through console I could find that my actor is able to receive the request and perform the action.  I do not know how to parse it back. I am trying to read the Future by using Await.result. But this Await.result  expects awaitable object. If I pass Future object, it throws compiler exception. Please help.

```
public Result invoke(String message) {

try {
    System.out.println("invoke ");
    MySampleMessage msg = new MySampleMessage(message);
    System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
    Future<Object> futr = (Future<Object>) Patterns.ask(myActor, msg, localConfig.getTimeOut());
    System.out.println("invoke 1");
    ////Promise<Object> promise = Promise.wrap(futfure);

    String msg1 = Await.result(futr, Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    System.out.println("invoke 2 ");
    return  play.mvc.Results.ok("Success " + msg1);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return (play.mvc.Results.ok("Exception"));
}

}
```

Is there any other way to parse the response back from an `async` actor ?

Comment: What exactly is the compiler exception you are having? Because if it is a "type mismatch" you just need to cast the `Await.result` value to a string like. `String msg1 = (String) Await.result(...)`.

Comment: I was getting an error like -  expected Awaitable<T>, but found scala.concurrent.Future at aruement{1} in Await.result

Answer (score 2):

You must be careful with name conflicts between standard java types and Akka types. For example, Java has a `java.util.concurrent.Future` type while Akka's `Patterns.ask()` returns a `akka.dispatch.Future`.

Check your cast to `Future<Object>`. It would never work at runtime and the type incompatibility is being detected later because Java's future as nothing to do with Akka's `Awaitable`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to parse the response back from actors. Create a function, wrap your future and map it to a function which will check the instance type of response and return Result. Below is the working code snippet.

```
Future<Object> futre = (Future<Object>) Patterns.ask(myActor, msg,      localConfig.getTimeOut());

F.Function<Object, Result> function = new F.Function<Object, Result>()
{
    public Result apply(Object response)
    {
        String s = String.valueOf(response);
        if(response instanceof String) return play.mvc.Results.ok(s);
        else  return play.mvc.Results.ok("fail");
    }
};

return Promise.wrap(futre).map(function);
```